# How can I send Excel range including header, in table, and email to list?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a requirement where I need to send timesheet data for the current week to each person separately in a table using Excel range:

[image]

I want to send first row data, including header, into table to joseph
then send row data into table to francis.

I have written below code but it sends entire data to each person.

```vb
Sub BulkMail()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    'Creating references to Application and MailItem Objects of Outlook
    Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    'Creating variable to hold values of different items of mail
    Dim sendTo, subj, atchmnt, msg, ccTo, bccTo As String
    Dim lstRow As Long
    'My data is on sheet "Exceltip.com" you can have any sheet name.
     
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    'Getting last row of containing email id in column 3.
    lstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    'Variable to hold all email ids
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:D" & lstRow)
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range("C2:C" & lstRow)
    'initializing outlook object to access its features
    Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
    On Error GoTo cleanup 'to handle any error during creation of object.
    'Loop to iterate through each row, hold data in of email in variables and send
    'mail to each email id.
    For Each cell In rng1
        sendTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 0).Value2
        On Error Resume Next 'to hand any error during creation of below object
        Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
        
        'Writing and sending mail in new mail
        With outMail
            .To = sendTo
            .cc = ""
            .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
            .Subject = timesheet
            '.Attachments.Add atchmnt
            '.Send 'this send mail without any notification. If you want see mail
            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0 'To clean any error captured earlier
        Set outMail = Nothing 'nullifying outmail object for next mail
    Next cell 'loop ends
cleanup: 'freeing all objects created
    Set outApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
    ' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
      SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
      Filename:=TempFile, _
      Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
      Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
      HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")
    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Because you send your `rng` into the `.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)` and `rng` is defined as `Set rng = Range("A1:D" & lstRow)` from A1 to D(LastRow). So you need to change this `.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)` to send only the range you want.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ but i need to select entire data sheet as it is dynamic in range. if i select only A1:F1 only first row will be sent to all persons. can you suggest me how to change it?

Comment: Well something like `.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(Application.Intersect(rng, Cell.EntireRow))` could work. • Also note that writing `Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 0).Value2` is exactly the same as writing just `cell.Offset(0, 0).Value2`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thank you for quick response , i tried the above one but it is not giving me the header with row , sorry too many questions but i am lil confused here how to put the row and header.

Comment: Well then add the header with `Union()` too: `.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML( Union(rng.Rows(1),Application.Intersect(rng, Cell.EntireRow)))`

Comment: I wrote it as an answer so you can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Application.Intersect(rng, Cell.EntireRow)` to get the part of the data of the current row. And `Union()` that with the header row before you push it into your `RangetoHTML()` function.

```
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(Union(rng.Rows(1), Application.Intersect(rng, Cell.EntireRow)))
```

Comment: @PEH , one more thing i want to ask can we get the first name from email id and address the person before inserting the table.

Comment: @chandrashekarpadmini if the email **always** follows the rule `firstname.lastname@xxx.com` then yes, you can extract the firstname from the email eg using `Split("firstname.lastname@xxx.com", ".")(0)`.

Comment: If i have one or more row of same person like below but i need to send only one email with both rows in one email :

Comment: Project  PSA Code Resources name Days Hours  Cost  Emailid
CCEBRS60TS  44182 Abdelkrim Ali-Bey 4.5 36.00 3489.12 abdelkrim.ali-bey@gmail.com
CCEADSME11 CR77WNP 42391 Abdelkrim Ali-Bey 0.375 3.00 290.76 abdelkrim.ali-bey@gmail.com
CCEADSME11 CR529 42391 Alain Doré 5 40.00 4626 alain.dore@gmail.com

Comment: Please note that your original question was anwsered and we cannot anwser new questions in comments. In this case it is much more complicated as you need to use autofilter and copy only the filtered data. Please do some research how to filer data and copy the filtered data. Try to accomplish what you want and if you get stuck or errors ask a new question. Note that we cannot write the code for you but if you make an attepmt we can tell what you did wrong and help you to fix it.

Comment: Hi Peh , thank you for the above solution and apologies for asking many questions in the same one. Above solution works but it is not giving me borders for each row. I have tried using Set rng = Range("A1:H" & lstRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) but still it doesn't give the border . can you answer or should i raise a new question